# Converting 3 column parent/child list into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a large csv file that has 3 columns:

```
Parent  Child   Qty
31282   42126A  0.00272
31282   50553   0.107
31282   61119   1
31283   42126A  0.00272
31283   50277   0.107
31283   61119   1
```

A Child can be a parent of other Children.

There could be a scenario of two identical children having different parents and therefore different quantities:

```
31254   31282   0.535
31255   31282   2.8448
```

I want to convert that into a dictionary, that includes the quantities.

So far I can make the dict with the following code:

```
has_parent = set()
all_items = {}
quan = []

for parent, child, qty in data:
    if parent not in all_items:
        all_items[parent] = {}
    if child not in all_items:
        all_items[child] = {}

    quan.append({'parent': parent,'child': child, 'qty': qty})

    all_items[parent][child] = all_items[child]
    has_parent.add(child)

result = {}
for key, value in all_items.items():
    if key not in has_parent:
        result[key] = value
```

The result dict looks like this:

```
 '31597': {'31598': {'42126A': {},
                     '50005A': {},
                     '50365': {},
                     '50393': {},
                     '53120': {},
                     '61554': {}}},
 '31599': {'31600': {'50398': {}}},
 '31601': {'31602': {'50399': {}}},
 '31603': {'31600': {'50398': {}}},
 '31604': {'31602': {'50399': {}}},
 '31605': {'31606': {'50403': {}}},
 '31607': {'31606': {'50403': {}}},
 '31609': {'31608': {'51037': {}, '52095': {}, '64041': {}}},
 '31612': {'31610': {'40098': {}, '60544': {}, '61501A': {}}},
```

My issue is how can I insert the QTY into the proper key.

I can find a key's parents and then look at the original file and see the quantity, but how can I insert that quantity at a depth of maybe 3 or 4 or more?

This is the output of a Child Key and its many parents.

```
60542
['31280', '31281', '31280', '31281']
----------
61554
['31596', '31598', '31280', '31281', '31280', '31281']
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't want to export this data into a sql database style of setup? gaining access to foreign keys would make this problem trivial.

Comment: Your result dict has information that isn't in the example csv input - it is hard to correlate the two.  Does the `QTY` field pertain to the `Child`, `Parent` or the `Parent-Child` combination? why did you choose a dictionary?

Comment: The QTY pertains to the Parent-Child combo, that would be unique and give me the proper qty.
Is there a better way instead of a dict?


As I'm creating the hierarchy I am ignoring the qty, I'm not sure how to keep it there and still get the tree that I need

Oh and yes, sorry, I copied the last few lines of the result dict. The original CSV has 80k lines worth of Parent-Child-Qty combos

Comment: As far importing into SQL, that is possible, I haven't looked into it. 
How would you use foreign keys in order to make this easier?

Comment: The end result of this exercise would be to convert the "flat" csv file into a Tree like csv file, this is a "tabified" tree of the dict: https://i.imgur.com/SgJ2ms9.png

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want an auxiliary data structure to keep track of the root-node that corresponds to the leaf you want to modify. A simple choice would be an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). This way you can know which node to start your search from.

Alternatively (and with greater simplicity), you could implement BFS/DFS, but the lack of structure in your data would ensure poor time-complexity.

Comment: I think you're right. 
I did something up and I think it worked using adjacency list. I will edit this if it works, thanks!